# How to use SQL Server Compact in Windows Phone without Linq to SQL

Tags: linq-to-sql, sql-server-ce, windows-phone

For a couple reasons, I'd like to avoid using Linq to SQL in my Windows Phone project, but I still want to use SQL Server Compact Edition. It looks like this isn't possible. For the life of me, I can't find the `SqlCeConnection` class. There doesn't seem to be a `System.Data.SqlServerCe` namespace (or dll) at all. Am I required to use Linq to SQL on Windows Phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access SQL Server Compact, only LINQ to SQL is available. What are your reasons, maybe they can be fixed in another way?

Comment: Mainly, I like to skip the middleman (the ORM) and write my SQL directly. I ended up using SQLite and creating my own Query() extension method similar to the way [Dapper](https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net) works.